# Infopath Lookup MultiChoice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a site column of type Choice named "Project" with Multiple values selection enabled.

This choice site column is used in two lists - ListA and List B

ListA is a lookup in List B. So when I select lookup value of List A in List B, selected Columns from List A should be auto populated in List B. I was able to lookup most of the fields but for field "Project" which is multi select choice, it selects only first value.

For e.g. In List A, For Item1, I have selected Choice1,Choice2,Choice3 in "Project", when I lookup Item1 in ListB, Only "Choice1" is selected.

I am using Infopath 2013, SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue, only the first choice value will be selected.

List A:

[image]

List B form:

[image]

InfoPath rule:

[image]

It occurs because we can only get the first value from ":Value".

Per my research, it is difficult to set multiple values to multiple-selection list box in InfoPath form.

As a workaround, an idea, you can get the lookup value from the form on the page. Then using CSOM/JSOM to find the item from List A based on the lookup value and get Project data from the List A item. If specific choice is contained in the List A item, use JavaScript to check the checkbox on the page (
e.g. `$("#checkboxId").attr('checked', true);`).